# течет память при добавлении объекта sprite kit objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritekit

[![в показателе memory память постоянно росла просто при добавлении физического тела на сцену в чем дело я не пойму 
вы не могли бы подсказать мне в чем дело ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oda.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oda.png)

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    _world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_world];
    _spinnyNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:(CGSize){50,50}];
    _spinnyNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _spinnyNode.warpGeometry = nil;
    [_world addChild:_spinnyNode];
    _spinnyNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_spinnyNode.frame.size];
    _spinnyNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
}
```

Comment: вы уже задавали этот вопрос. зачем его задавать заново? напишите комментарий к прошлому

Comment: в xcode нажмите command+i, там выберите 'leaks' и в нем посмотрите есть ли утечки памяти. потом напишите сюда где как и сколько течет. потом будем говорить

Comment: В instruments, leak говорит что утечек нет, но в левой части показатель memory постоянно растёт, а я все го лишь добавил физическое тело на сцену

Comment: ну видите, память не течет. возможно, вы где то постоянно добавляете новые объекты или еще что то такое. давайте код смотреть

Comment: - (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    _world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_world];
    
    _spinnyNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:(CGSize){50,50}];
    _spinnyNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    _spinnyNode.warpGeometry = nil;
    [_world addChild:_spinnyNode];
    
    _spinnyNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_spinnyNode.frame.size];
    _spinnyNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
}

Comment: можно в вопрос добавить?

Comment: вот и весь код. просто положил физическое тело на сцену и все. дело в том что я около 2-х лет использую Sprite Kit и такая проблем с утечкой памяти началась с IOS 9

Comment: может я что то не так делаю, может я что то пропустил в этой теме

Comment: все таки код можно в вопрос добавить - без форматирования его читать невозможно

Comment: /Users/dmitriyshevelev/Desktop/Снимок экрана 2016-11-08 в 23.18.37.png

Comment: да не в комментарий а в сам вопрос - там можно форматирование делать

Comment: блин я не знаю как ) разберусь

Comment: ладно, я уже сам сделал. Короче, в этом коде ничего вроде течь не должно. Можете весь проект показать, если хотите. либо ставьте где то брейкпоинты и смотрите, нет ли кусков кода, которые выполняются больше чем надо раз

Comment: попробуйте создать такой же проект Sprite Kit повторить код и у вас тоже потечет память

Comment: может вы проще где то расшарьте свой да я посмотрю

Comment: секундочку сейчас

Comment: вот ссылка  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiytSMIQbPzZ1JVOWctSXF4WDg

Comment: я тестирую на реальном устройстве в моем случае это iPhone 5S, симулятор не покажет утечки в строке memory я пробовал

Comment: А разве addChild не добавляет единичку к retainCount?  Может быть в конце сетода просто присвоить _world = nil и _spinnyMode = nil ?

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, есть такая проблема - течет память в physicsBody. Исправить ее по всей видимости невозможно - она на стороне apple. Нашел какой то радар на эту тему. Больше пока ничего посоветовать не могу.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27870

Comment: я тоже все перерыл и тоже видел этот форум. огромное вам спасибо за  отклик на мою проблему